# How can I enable the web-bluetooth Debug Logs on Mac?

Tags: web-bluetooth

I'm attempting to file a bug for web bluetooth. I attempted to enable the Chrome Debug Logs on Mac, but the instructions on the following site may be out of date.

https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/file-web-bluetooth-bugs/

I tried to follow these instructions.

Chrome logs
Quit any running instance of Chrome.
Launch /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app
At the command prompt enter: /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --enable-logging=stderr --vmodule=*bluetooth*=2

I expected to see the command complete successfully and begin viewing logs on

chrome://bluetooth-internals/#debug

When I run the command in Terminal, I receive the following response.

zsh: no matches found: --vmodule=*bluetooth*=2

MacOS Monterey Version 12.6.3
Chrome Version 109.0.5414.119 (Official Build)(x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

These instructions seem to be written for bash. I was using zsh.

zsh doesn't interpret wildcards in command arguments the same way. The wildcards (*) cause the error.

One solution to this problem is to manually enter bash on Mac by executing 'bash' in the terminal. At that point, you can run the recommended debug command without getting any errors.